# To run selectively failed http requests(via counter) using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am performing provisioning performance tests using JMeter. I need to provision DB with 40 million entities using REST/http requests. I am incrementing counter to generate unique IDs for provisioning request.

While running these loads, some requests fail (~3k). To provision these,I need to run the complete load again (this way I get failures for entities already created,but the previous failures are re-attempted).
Is there a clean way to do this,where only failures can be re-attempted?

Comment: you could retry immediately after it failed (and not wait for next execution).

Comment: You should have a look at your application to see what exactly is going wrong. If the only task of that JMeter execution is to fill data into your database, you'd better do that on another way

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.I run the tests in loop to get the performance figures and cant stop in between. Also,the application errors are under analysis but meanwhile,I need a way to execute only failed requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can save for every failure the id in in new line in a file. Use JSR223 Post processor to check failure and save to file

Then  execute a reattempt using a new jmx with [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) reading the file until end of file and executing your tests with failed IDs you can use [include controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) to execute the jmx and pass the unique id using property.

> The include controller is designed to use an external JMX file